# Code that detects a mobile device and offers to add link to home screen

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile

I'm looking for some code to place on my website, which detects if the user is on a mobile device, opens a pop-up and offers to add an icon on the home screen linking to the website. (Just like adding the website to your favorites and placing an icon on the home screen). Ideally it should work on Android & iPhone. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a div somewhere on your page, with the exact text you want. In your CSS, you then make the div display:none and add a media query so when the device is a mobile phone you display the div again.

```
.mobile-div {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .mobile-div {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Ofcourse you can expand on this by having a javascript function checking for the screen width, and use functions to open a popup when a certain width is reached (and is thus considered a mobile phone).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var width = $(window).width();

        if (width < 400) {
            // do something
        }
    })();
</script>
```

You can then search Google for a way of actually making the icon, for example this script might help you: https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/wiki/Mobile-Bookmark-Bubble. Although I think it is not possible in iOS to do this, you might have to consider creating an app that basically launches your website, or something similar. Ofcourse this will mean you have to pay for your app being displayed in the store, so it comes down to you: Do you really need this functionality, or not?

Comment: How will this add an icon on the home page of the mobile device, can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse this will not add an icon, this is the part where you can detect if an user is on a mobile phone and then do something either in the div or in a JS function.

Comment: Thanks for these useful insights, I'm going to try this out.